# what is the %2d in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I know the meaning of this statement

```
scanf("%d",&x);
```

But what does this statement do

```
scanf("%2d",&x);
```

I tried searching for this, but could not find an answer. I want to know what happens internally also.

Comment: The thing you should search for is the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for the `scanf()` function. It's not very hard to find. Read it, many times.

Comment: `%nd` in `scanf()` read decimal integer atleast `n` characters wide.

Comment: @SunilBojanapally: not "at least" but "at most".  It will stop after fewer than _n_ characters if it comes across something that is not numeric (letters, spaces, punctuation, EOF, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's two digits number:

```
int n = 0;
scanf ("%2d", &n);
printf ("-> %d\n", n);
```

12
-> 12

88657
-> 88

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this - scanf("%2d.%d",&x)?

Comment: @Ashwin Yes, but you're going to need another variable: `scanf("%2d.%d", &x, &y);` since you're doing two conversions. Remember to check the return value.

Comment: Note that both `23.000567` and `23.567` will give you `567` in your second variable; however, the meaning of the two strings is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

The number right after the '%' sign and right before the type of data you wish to read represents the maximum size of that specific type of data.

As you are reading an integer (%2d), it will only allow an integer up to **two** digits long. If you were to read a 50 characters long array, you should use %49s (leaving one for the null terminating byte). It is the same idea.

```
int number = 0;
scanf("%2d", &number);
printf("%d", number);
```

If the user passed 21 for the scanf() function, the number 21 would be stored in the variable number. If the user passed something longer than 21, i.e. 987, only the first 2 digits would be stored - 98.