# What is a %2s and %2d command in C, and when i use it?

Tags: c

I would like to know why i use %2s here:

```
char card_name[3];
puts ("Enter the card name: ");
scanf ("%2s, card_name);
```

And why i use %2d:

```
int n = 0;
scanf ("%2d", &n);
printf ("-> %d\n", n);
```

Comment: How should we know? We're in no way responsible for what you decided to write.

Comment: Your third line won't compile. Please make 100% percent sure you copy and paste code that works.

Comment: have you looked up the documentation of scanf?

Comment: Please RTFM here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2 for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the %2d in scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913848/what-is-the-2d-in-scanf)

Comment: Have you ever heard of the man pages??

Comment: Why bother, if someone else will look it up for you?  That is what SO is for - to get other people to do all your work, no matter how menial.:(

Answer (score 6):

You chose the `%2s` format specifier as you expect to read `a string of size 2` and `%2d` as you wanted to output `a two digit decimal number`.

See [documentation of scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for further details.

Comment: Ty, you solve my problem :D