# printf("%2d") in C programming

Tags: c, printf

I saw so many question and answer on stackoverflow and other sites but I am so confused that when %2d created 2 character spaces and we want to execute this code then what should happen?

```
int a = 20011;
printf("%2d\n",a);
```

According to my point of view it should print only 2 character wide but when we print then it print whole character. Why?

I have edited this question.
Now I would like to know that what is used of - sign. I have read so many articles that says - sign tells the left alignment but when it is used give with example.
for example:

```
int str[] = "skgskg";
 printf("%2s\n",str);
```

Comment: It only affects string representations that are less than 2 characters wide. If more are needed, it will still output all.

Comment: `printf` and friends only support a max field width for strings. There is no way to limit how many characters are printed for an integral value. The width specification is the *minimum* width, not the *exact* width.

Comment: Points of view don’t matter much. What matters is what the standard says: `printf` is a C standard function. That’s where the meaning of the format string is defined. And the meaning is such that `2` in your case is the minimum width: if `a` is zero, there would be padding added, since `0` is only one character wide :).

Comment: Suppose %2s instead of %2d and string like this char str[] = "geeksforgeeks"; what will be output

Comment: Could you tell me when we write %-2s then what will affect. When i see the output then I see that no any change in output

Comment: "geeksforgeeks". To limit the string length, you need to use the precision field: `printf("%.2s", "geeksforgeeks")` prints "ge".

Comment: Read [the relevant standard paragraph](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4) and ask if something is not clear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please explain the meaning of - for example %-2s when it will use

Comment: You  can't have read that helpful link in less than 1 minute, which clearly answers that.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p6 - *The flag characters and their meanings are:

**'-'**
The result of the conversion is left-justified within the field. (It is right-justified if this flag is not specified.)*  And then comes the minimum width specifier

Comment: "*what will be output*" - Why are you asking thousands of people online? You could either just try it or read the documentation for `printf` (and if anything is unclear, ask a specific question about that).

Comment: @melpomene. Hi I have read so many articles about it but I am so confused because when we execute the code then we find no change in output for example: %2s and %-2s then no any changes in output

Comment: I suggest you try it with a number smaller than the field width. For example if the field width is `%2d` try it with a number in the range 0..9. Or with your value, a greater field width, such as `int a = 20011; printf("%10d\n",a);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the %2d in scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913848/what-is-the-2d-in-scanf)

Comment: Note, your question is not mentioning the `-` flag which you are insisting on asking about in the comments.

Comment: @davedwards No, that question is about `scanf`, not `printf`.

Comment: @melpomene correct, because that is what [What is the use and meaning of %2d in c? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448726/what-is-the-use-and-meaning-of-2d-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a duplicate of

Comment: @davedwards Not anymore.

Answer (score 8):

It specifies the  **minimum** width that the output should be. If the width specified is more than the size of the output itself (the opposite of your case), then the difference between the length of your output and the width specified will be printed as spaces before your output.

So for example, `printf("%2d\n", 12345);` will just print `12345`, since `12345` has 5 digits, but the width specified is only 2.

However, `printf("%10d\n", 12345);` will print `_____12345` (5 spaces before `12345`) since the difference between the width exceeds the length of the output by 5.

Comment: So wouldn't it be better, then, to say "it specifies the *minimum* width of the output"?  That emphasizes the detail that seems to be confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Per the C standard, this number is the **minimum** field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the minimum field with, it is padded with spaces. If it has the same number or more, the entire converted value is printed—it is not reduced to the given width.

Quoting from C 2018 7.21.6.1 4:

> An optional minimum *field width*. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width. The field width takes the form of an asterisk * (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.

That is just part of paragraph 4. In its entirety, it gives the entire format of a conversion specification, which is a `%` followed by:

> — Zero or more *flags* (in any order) that modify the meaning of the conversion specification.
>
> — An optional minimum *field width*. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width. The field width takes the form of an asterisk `*` (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.
>
> — An optional *precision* that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for the `g` and `G` conversions, or the maximum number of bytes to be written for `s` conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional nonnegative decimal integer; if only the period is specified, the precision is taken as zero. If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.
>
> — An optional *length modifier* that specifies the size of the argument.
>
> — A *conversion specifier* character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.